# Guessing the number of other $1$'s in a binary sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, information-theory, coding-theory

Consider the set of all binary sequence of length $n+1$, $B=\big\{(b_i)_{i=0}^n\,\big| b_i\in\{0,1\}, \forall i\big\}$. Construct a function $f: \{0,\cdots,n\}\times \{0,1\}\to \{0,\cdots, n\}$, such that  $\forall (b_i)_{i=0}^n\in B,\,\exists i\ni f(i,b_i)=\sum_{j\ne i}b_j$.

What is a systematic way to construct this function?

---

Putting it more colloquially, we assign $n+1$ persons one-to-one to all the digits of an arbitrary binary sequence of length $n+1$. Each person can see but the digit assigned to him. Devise a strategy so that at least one person guesses correctly the sum of the remaining digits other than his own.

---

Epilogue: It was [answered brilliantly on Mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/a/342264/32660) after I posted the question there.

Comment: What is meant by $$\sum_{i\ne i}$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Oops. Typo. Just corrected.

Comment: Please either delete this question or add an answer.

Comment: @leonbloy: I added an answer but was automatically converted into a comment as I suppose it was too short. So I put it as an epilogue into the question.

Comment: But the question shows as unanswered. I suggest you delete it (sadly the "close"  button sucks)

Comment: " the sum of the remaining digits.", So their own digit?

Comment: Or I guess I don't understand "Each person can see but the digit assigned to him". Did you mean "can't see anything but" or "can see only"

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi: The three phrases are equivalent. "But" here means "only". I edited the last sentence to "the sum of the remaining digits other than his own" so as to be absolutely clear.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the answer by Bullet51 posted on MO.
https://mathoverflow.net/a/342264/32660

Since every person knows his assigned digit, the problem is equivalent to guessing the sum of all digits.

Label the persons with $0,1,...,n$. Let person $0$ guess $0$ when given a $0$, and $n+1$ when given a $1$. Let person $k$ guess $k$ for every $k\in \{1,...,n\}$.

At least one person can correctly guess the sum of all digits. So when they subtract their given digit from the guessed sum, at least one person can correctly guess the sum of the remaining digits.